# C++, execute 1 loop per mouse click?

Tags: c++, click, mouse

I am new with C++ and I was wondering if someone can help me out.  What would be the correct loop structure be to print "hello world" on a left mouse click in the DOS window?

I did some searches and I arrived at something like

```
if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0) 
{
   printf("Hello World!\n"); 
}
```

Or would an event be better?

The " hello world" is going to be a code to capture images from a webcam.  The original tutorial code has a while loop (always true) which ends up streaming the video.  My goal is to capture 1 frame via mouse click.  I'm trying to get a simplified version working with this hello world thing.

Comment: thank you all for the replies.  I would +1 you guys, but I can't seem to yet.  I'll need some time to digest this

Answer (score 0):

They way you are doing it right now, you may not get the desired results.  Think about the mouse as if it was running on a separate thread.  When you call your line of code to see if the mouse was pressed, it may be false, even though the user pressed the mouse in that particular frame.

```
some code            <-- mouse button pressed by user
some code            <-- mouse button released by user
some code
your mouse check     <-- mouse button check is false (undesired result)
some code
some code
```

Events solve this problem because the press and release interrupts are stored in a buffer (by the OS).  This eliminates the issue of timing.  I'm not sure what library you are using, but if it's anything like sdl or sfml, then you can use the event loop to decide what to do.

The event loop (which is in a "Big Game Loop") should look something like:

```
while(there's still events){
    if(mouse press event){
        do what you want on mouse press
    }
}
```

Because there could be multiple mouse press events between any two frames, I would create a bool mouseWasPressed default false, and set it true if the desired event occured.

```
bool mouseWasPressed = false;
while(there's still events){
    if(mouse press event){
        if(!mouseWasPressed){
            mouseWasPressed = true;
            capture frame for video
        }
    }
}
```

this way you eliminate multiple mouse press events per frame (even thought they are unlikely).  When I say mouse press event, I am assuming you are filtering on a particular mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop if you want to repeat capture for each click (what your title implies ...). It would then be an active loop (in pseudo code)

```
while true {
    if _mouse_click_ {
        // your stuff
    }
}
```

It is allways better to use an event loop (I presume you are on Windows), because the OS gives time slices to your prog only when event occurs instead of letting your prog waste time slices testing the occurence ... and possibly starving other apps ...

Answer (score 0):

For mouse handling in a console window, use `ReadConsoleInput` and check if the event  `Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED` has happened. And then  paste
your webcam code in there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{ 
    cout<<"click anywhere in console window to write - hello world -\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    "Press Ctrl+C to Exit"; 

        HANDLE hout= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        HANDLE hin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
        INPUT_RECORD InputRecord; 
        DWORD Events; 
        COORD coord;
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
        cci.dwSize = 25;
        cci.bVisible = FALSE;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(hout, &cci); 
        SetConsoleMode(hin, ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT); 


    while(1)
    { 

        ReadConsoleInput(hin, &InputRecord, 1, &Events); 

        if(InputRecord.EventType == MOUSE_EVENT) 
        {
            if(InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED) 
            { 
                coord.X = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X; 
                coord.Y = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y; 
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hout,coord);
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hout,rand() %7+9);

                cout<<"Hello world" ; 

            } 
        }
        FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hin);
    }
    return 0;

}
```